# Using Sangria with Scala 3

Tags: scala, graphql, akka-http, scala-3, sangria

Are there any examples of using Sangria with a Scala 3 program, or is that a non-starter? Using cross-compilation in SBT builds OK, but getting a `NoSuchMethodError` exception in `Executor.execute` when I send a query.

`build.sbt` looks like this:

```scala
val AkkaVersion = "2.6.21"
val SangriaAkkaHttpVersion = "0.0.4"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.13.5", "3.3.0")
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.3.0"

("com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % AkkaVersion).cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13),
("com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-typed" % AkkaVersion).cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13),
("org.sangria-graphql" %% "sangria-akka-http-circe" % SangriaAkkaHttpVersion).cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13),
```

Any clues as to how to get this to work?

Error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.runtime.BoxedUnit sangria.execution.Executor$.execute$default$4()'
    at XXX.graphql.GraphQlServer$$anon$1.applyOrElse(GraphQlServer.scala:55)
    at XXX.graphql.GraphQlServer$$anon$1.applyOrElse(GraphQlServer.scala:49)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:35)
    at sangria.http.akka.SangriaAkkaHttp.$anonfun$prepareGraphQLPost$2(SangriaAkkaHttp.scala:137)
```

Comment: Akka 2.6.21 is released for Scala 3 - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor-typed, Sangra as well - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sangria-graphql/sangria . Only this "akka-http-circe" bridge is not available for Scala 3... but it's literary [a single file](https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria-akka-http/blob/main/circe/src/main/scala/sangria/http/akka/circe/CirceHttpSupport.scala) - I would just remove `CrossVersion.for3Use2_13` and copy-pasted the source of this single file adding a comment to use library once it's published.

Comment: Could you share the complete error message and the related code?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately `sangria-akka-http-circe` depends on `sangria-akka-http-core` which is also still at Scala 2 and is a more comprehensive piece of code.

Comment: I looked at it and I would still give it a chance. I had a similar problem a few years ago: I temporarily needed to use a library which had bugs, which were fixed in much later version than I had and bumping library would be a several day long process and hardly justifiable effort. (I the fix was needed for migrating all data from this service to a new one). I downloaded the whole source code locally, edited and published locally, and when I saw that this worked I "inlined" this library as a module in my project, to be able to easily build the image in CI. It was also about Akka and its plugin

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok The real blocker turns out to be that the version of `akka-http` that supports Scala 3 requires `akka` 2.7 which would add a $4,000 licence to our $400 product. I wonder how `pekko` is doing ...

Comment: [Pekko is doing great.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pekko/pekko-http) For the time being, if your product generates "less than US $25 million in annual revenue" I would suggest to apply for the license, use no Akka-2.7-specific feature, migrate to Scala 3 and use the bought time to migrate to Pekko with no hurry. Unless the project was small enough to migrate it with 1 PR, because then I would do just that.

Comment: The project is $1-2M but company is $50-100M so don't think I can escape the full cost. Will explore pekko...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the quickest solution was to switch from `akka` to `pekko` (painless) and modify the `akka-http` helpers for `sangria` to use `pekko-http`.

Specifically, I cloned `sangria-akka-http-core`, `sangria-akka-http-circe`, and `akka-http-circe`, and replaced `import akka` with `import org.apache.pekko`. Other than that the main issues were with the build process rather than the code.

Hopefully there will be official `pekko` versions of these libraries at some point.

Comment: There are 2 pekko-http-circe libs - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mdedetrich/pekko-http-circe and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.pjfanning/pekko-http-circe. Regarding Sangria, maybe you could donate your changes to the Sangria org.

Comment: Not sure how I missed them, thanks for the update (and thanks for not just promoting your own library!)

Comment: @PJFanning I have implementations of `sangria-pekko-http-core` and `sangria-pekko-http-circe` which I am happy to donate, but not in a position to do any publishing work myself. They are also pretty trivial to implement based on the akka version so probably easier for the Sangria org to do it themselves.